# How does webpack uses polyfill?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-module-loader

I'm using webpack with babel polyphill so I can write my code in es6.

I don't understand how does webpack use polyfill so my code can be supported in browsers like IE?

For example, let say we have a simple class

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.name = 'Polygon';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  } 
}
```

Since IE doesn't understand what the class keyword is, my code need to be change to:

```
function Polygon(height, width) {
    this.name = 'Polygon';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
```

Is that changes occur on run time (using something like a reference to the code that should be interpreted) or is webpack compiling my code so that resulted code is only the es5?

I mean, if that occur on run time, I will have more code in my bundle: the code I wrote + polyphill...

Indeed, when using webpack, my code is (a lot) bigger.

If it doesn't occur on run time so why do I have to include polyphill to my dependencies (instead of in my dev dependencies)?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is webpack compiling my code so that resulted code is only the es5?

**Yes. Webpack includes `babel-polyfill` code to your result bundle**.

So if you use native `Promise`, `babel-polyfill` will set own implementation to global namespace(window.Promise).
There is also `babel-runtime` package which does not touch global namespace and resolves your `Promise` in code as local module during webpack bundling.

> If it doesn't occur on run time so why do I have to include polyphill to my dependencies (instead of in my dev dependencies)?

Because `babel-polyfill` is required module for **your application to work correctly** **on run-time**. `dependencies` are required to run app, `devDependencies` only for development, transpilation, testing, etc. So example `babel` - transpiler (devDependency), `babel-polyfill` provides missing functionality(api not syntax) to app (dependency).